what is the best way to conditionally render a signup page if the user is not logged it in the new expo file based router?
I want the app to render the signup page if the user is not logged in. But the issue right now is that  when the app loads, it loads the Stack screen but will the same contents and layout as the Drawer screens. Meaning, the signup page never gets to be loaded. In my DataContext, i intentionally made user a Boolean and set it to false in order for the signup page to load yet it still loads the Stack but with the Drawer screen. I had to change the user to true and back to false for the signup page to now load. I'm not a quite familiar with the new expo file based router and the Stacks, Drawers and Slot. So I need help.
import {
  DarkTheme,
  DefaultTheme,
  ThemeProvider,
} from "@react-navigation/native";
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
import { useRouter, useFocusEffect, Stack } from "expo-router";
import * as SplashScreen from "expo-splash-screen";
import { useEffect, useCallback, useContext, useState } from "react";
import "react-native-reanimated";
import { useColorScheme } from "@/hooks/useColorScheme";
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { Drawer } from "expo-router/drawer";
import DataProvider, { DataContext } from "@/dataContext/DataContext";
import { MaterialIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute } from "@react-navigation/native";

// Prevent the splash screen from auto-hiding before asset loading is complete.
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

function AunthenticatedDrawer() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();
  const router = useRouter();

  const updateHeaderTitle = useCallback((navigation, route) => {
    useFocusEffect(
      useCallback(() => {
        const routeName = getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route) ?? "Home";
        let title = "";
        switch (routeName) {
          case "index":
            title = "Questions";
            break;
          case "myCourses":
            title = "My Courses";
            break;
          case "inbox":
            title = "Messages";
            break;
          case "creator":
            title = "Create";
            break;
          case "profile":
            title = "Profile";
            break;

          default:
            break;
        }
        navigation.setOptions({ title: title });
      }, [navigation, route])
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <Drawer
      screenOptions={{
        headerTintColor: colorScheme === "dark" ? "white" : "black",
        headerRight: () => (
          <MaterialIcons
            name="notifications"
            color={colorScheme === "dark" ? "white" : "black"}
            size={23}
            onPress={() => router.push("/notifications")}
          />
        ),
      }}
    >
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="authenticated/(tabs)"
        options={({ navigation, route }) => {
          updateHeaderTitle(navigation, route);
          return { drawerLabel: "Home", title: "" };
        }}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="authenticated/question/[id]"
        options={{
          drawerLabel: "Question",
          drawerItemStyle: { display: "none" },
          title: "",
        }}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="authenticated/notifications"
        options={{ drawerLabel: "Notifications" }}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="+not-found"
        options={{ drawerItemStyle: { display: "none" } }}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="authenticated/report/[id]"
        options={{
          title: "Report",
          drawerItemStyle: { display: "none" },
        }}
      />
    </Drawer>
  );
}

function UnAuthenticatedStack() {
  return (
    <Stack
      screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
      initialRouteName="unauthenticated/signup"
    >
      <Stack.Screen name="unauthenticated/signup" />
    </Stack>
  );
}

function RootLayout() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();
  const [loaded] = useFonts({
    SpaceMono: require("../assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf"),
  });
  const { user } = useContext(DataContext);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (loaded) {
      SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [loaded]);

  if (!loaded) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <ThemeProvider value={colorScheme === "dark" ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}>
      <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        {user ? <AunthenticatedDrawer /> : <UnAuthenticatedStack />}
      </GestureHandlerRootView>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default function AppLayout() {
  return (
    <DataProvider>
      <RootLayout />
    </DataProvider>
  );
}


You can make Splash screen as custom and there you can use setTimeout to appear your desire page. You can use the condition into setTimeout function. If the user is not logged in then open signup page otherwise open home page.
const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(true);
setTimeout(() => {
  if(loggedIn){
    navigation.navigate('screenWithDrawer')
  }else{
    navigation.navigate('home')
  }     
}, 3000);

